# Make Text Pop Up in Raphael JS Map

Tags: raphael

I found code that will nicely display an interactive map of the US where each state is color coded onmouseover; however, I'd like to now add a popup window or side textbox that displays the name of each state onmouseover. Any help would be appreciated. HTML code for interactive US map
[image]

Comment: To elaborate, I'd like to display the name of the "state" when the mouse hovers over a particular state. I tried adding "usMap[state].txt.show()" in the onmouseover function above but with little success. The line "alert(state):" does work, but erradically.

Comment: Please post code as text (rather than screenshot) and use formatting options provided